# How to sample a value n from one distribution and take n values from another distribution

Tags: pymc3

Disclaimer: I have no idea what I'm doing, in either pymc3 or Bayesian statistics, but I'm trying to learn by diving straight in...

What I think I want to do is:

- I have one distribution, A, representing a frequency of events
- I have another distribution, B, representing a "cost" of each event
- I want to use a sampled frequency, n, from A and sample n costs from B
- The result I care about from each draw is the sum of costs

So each draw I would have a variable number of values from B.

My naive attempt to code this was:

```python
with pm.Model() as model:
    events = pm.Poisson("events", mu=5)
    count = events.random()
    losses = [
        pm.Lognormal(f"loss[{i}]", 1.2, 0.2)
        for i in range(count)
    ]
    year_loss = pm.Deterministic("year_loss", pm.math.sum(losses))

    trace = pm.sample(draws=500, chains=1)

    total_loss = trace.get_values("year_loss").sum()
    print(f"total_loss: {total_loss}")
    mean_loss = total_loss / 500
    print(f"mean_loss: {mean_loss}")
```

This "sort of works" in that I can get some output like:

```
Sequential sampling (1 chains in 1 job)
CompoundStep
>Metropolis: [events]
>NUTS: [loss[4], loss[3], loss[2], loss[1], loss[0]]
Sampling 1 chain for 1_000 tune and 500 draw iterations (1_000 + 500 draws total) took 2 seconds.02<00:00 Sampling chain 0, 0 divergences]
Only one chain was sampled, this makes it impossible to run some convergence checks
total_loss: 8431.667563769252
mean_loss: 16.8633351275385
```

But what is really happening is that `count` only has a single value across all draws in the trace.

Instead I wanted it to have an independent value for each draw.

Can someone kindly point me in the right direction?

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a simulation for these events and costs and don't want to "learn"/"fit" anything from observed data. If so, I don't think PyMC3 is the tool for the job. The main pymc usage is defining a model generatively (so it does kind of look like a simulation not too different from your code) in order to generate some observations from the model parameters, this therefore culminates using the `observed` argument in one of the random variables and passing whatever you have observed there for PyMC3 to infer the posterior probability of the model parameters given this data

Comment: @OriolAbril I think you must be right. I managed to make a "simulation" version just with numpy quite easily. I had assumed PyMC3 was a way of expressing such a model symbolically so it could be compiled with Theano/Jax backend, but clearly I misunderstood and it's not exactly that at all.